# difference between core connections and i/o threads in Datastax Cassandra C++ driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I set number of core connections per host using `cass_cluster_set_max_connections_per_host()` and i/o threads using `cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io()`. 
I see that my client host is establishing, 
**core connections * num i/o threads**, number of tcp connections with each host in my cluster using netstat command. I am wondering what is the difference between an i/o thread and a core connection? Also, if a client is communicating with Cassandra cluster of 10 hosts and number of core connections is set to 2, i/o threads is set to 4 then there are essentially 10*4*2, 80 connections established from a host to cluster - and this all in single session, how are those connections utilized? doesn't it seem extraneous?

I am trying to tune those values so if a cluster is connected by 100 hosts simultaneously then the speed wouldn't slow down. Or are those settings unrelated to speed? Any more information or links are appreciated!

Comment: "10k hosts" - that's *ambitious*.

Comment: I meant to just emphasize on multiple clients not on exact number of hosts, anyway I have modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official documentation of the fields present [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/cpp-driver/1.0/api/struct.CassCluster/#function-cass_cluster_set_max_connections_per_host)

**cass_cluster_set_num_threads_io** : This is the number of threads that will handle query requests. Default value: 1

**cass_cluster_set_max_connections_per_host**: Sets the maximum number of connections made to each server in each IO thread. Default value : 2

> I am wondering what is the difference between an i/o thread and a
>   core connection?

I/O threads are basically responsible for doing all the network operations between the Client and the Server. So if you have 1000 message waiting for the network operation, this thread will pick the request one by one and execute them. The default value is 1.

Once a message is picked by the I/O thread, it uses the connections specified in **set_max_connections** to make the request. The default value is 2 for this so that the I/O thread can intelligently switch connections based on server latency and throughput.

> I am trying to tune those values so if a cluster is connected by 100
>   hosts simultaneously then the speed wouldn't slow down.

You can either keep max connection constant and increase the number of i/o threads or the other way around for scaling. There is no clear *better* approach between the two. You will need to benchmark and see what approach works for your case.

I think that if you have less number of request but they are big request then increasing the number of connections makes more sense but it still requires benchmarking.

[This](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/pooling/) link also provides some extra info.

Comment: thanks @Abhishek your explanation made sense. I did some speed/scalability tests by keeping core connections constant and varying number of i/o threads and vice versa but didn't see any significant difference. Maybe different topic - do you have any idea why row with 8 kb blob results in much higher speed than a blob with 16 bytes?

Comment: I will need more details on that to answer it like the table schema, type of query, etc so probably you should ask it as a separate question. If you think this question is answered, you can accept this one as answered.